# Is it safe to hide sending to channel behind function call

Tags: go, concurrency, channel, goroutine

I have a struct called `Hub` with a `Run()` method which is executed in its own goroutine. This method sequentially handles incoming messages. Messages arrive concurrently from multiple producers (separate goroutines). Of course I use a `channel` to accomplish this task. But now I want to hide the `Hub` behind an `interface` to be able to choose from its implementations. So, using a `channel` as a simple `Hub`'s field isn't appropriate.

```
package main
import "fmt"
import "time"

type Hub struct {
    msgs chan string
}
func (h *Hub) Run() {
    for {
        msg, hasMore := <- h.msgs
        if !hasMore {
            return
        }
        fmt.Println("hub: msg received", msg)
    }
}
func (h *Hub) SendMsg(msg string) {
    h.msgs <- msg
}

func send(h *Hub, prefix string) {
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        fmt.Println("main: sending msg")
        h.SendMsg(fmt.Sprintf("%s %d", prefix, i))
    }
}

func main() {
    h := &Hub{make(chan string)}
    go h.Run()
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        go send(h, fmt.Sprintf("msg sender #%d", i))
    }
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
}
```

So I've introduced `Hub.SendMsg(msg string)` function that just calls `h.msgs <- msg` and which I can add to the `HubInterface`. And as a `Go`-newbie I wonder, is it safe from the concurrency perspective? And if so - is it a common approach in `Go`?

Playground [here](https://play.golang.org/p/As7ZqiwWJT).

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure how else to answer, because I'm unsure what would lead you to believe it could be unsafe.

Comment: @JimB, actually, after thinking awhile how it works under the hood I realized that the answer is pretty obvious as far as writing to the channel is thread-safe.

Comment: _A single channel may be used in send statements, receive operations, and calls to the built-in functions cap and len by any number of goroutines without further synchronization._ Fore more, see [If I am using channels properly should I need to use mutexes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34039229/if-i-am-using-channels-properly-should-i-need-to-use-mutexes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Channel send semantics do not change when you move the send into a method. Andrew's answer points out that the channel needs to be created with `make` to send successfully, but that was always true, whether or not the send is inside a method.

If you are concerned about making sure callers can't accidentally wind up with invalid `Hub` instances with a `nil` channel, one approach is to make the struct type private (`hub`) and have a `NewHub()` function that returns a fully initialized `hub` wrapped in your interface type. Since the struct is private, code in other packages can't try to initialize it with an incomplete struct literal (or any struct literal).

That said, it's *often* possible to create invalid or nonsense values in Go and that's accepted: `net.IP("HELLO THERE BOB")` is valid syntax, or `net.IP{}`. So if you think it's better to expose your `Hub` type go ahead.

Answer (score -1):

**Easy answer**

*Yes*

**Better answer**

*No*

Channels are great for emitting data from unknown go-routines. They do so safely, however I would recommend being careful with a few parts. In the listed example the channel is created with the construction of the struct by the consumer (and not not by a consumer).

Say the consumer creates the Hub like the following: `&Hub{}`. Perfectly valid... Apart from the fact that all the invokes of `SendMsg()` will block for forever. Luckily you placed those in their own go-routines. So you're still fine right? Wrong. You are now leaking go-routines. Seems fine... until you run this for a period of time. Go encourages you to have valid zero values. In this case `&Hub{}` is not valid.

Ensuring `SendMsg()` won't block could be achieved via a `select{}` however you then have to decide what to do when you encounter the default case (e.g. throw data away). The channel could block for more reasons than bad setup too. Say later you do more than simply print the data after reading from the channel. What if the read gets very slow, or blocks on IO. You then will start pushing back on the producers.

Ultimately, channels allow you to not think much about concurrency... However if this is something of high-throughput, then you have quite a bit to consider. If it is production code, then you need to understand that your API here involves `SendMsg()` blocking.

Comment: This is actively confusing; the question asked was whether channel send semantics are changed by moving the send into a function, and they aren't. `&Hub{}` is an invalid value of the type full-stop whether the channel send is inside a function call or not.