# How to decide between a context.WithDeadline or a simple timer?

Tags: go, timer, transactions

In Golang, I am fairly new to the *intentions* of passing `contexts` downstream to other methods and functions. I understand how a `context` works, how it is used, how it holds its values, how it's related to the parent `context` and their behaviors -- I just don't understand *why* to use a context in the first place.

In a more specific example, which is the actual reason of this question, in the company I work for, we have identified some very long-running queries that happen every so often due to an edge case.

An obvious solution we decided to take, given our constraints until we invest time to fix the root cause, is to kill the queries that take more than 5 minutes.

The method that runs our transactions accepts a `context` which is originally initiated in the API call. This `context` is passed down all the way to the transaction function. At that moment I found 2 solutions to kill that query:

1) Using a new context:

- Initiate a new `context.WithTimeout(ctx, time.Duration( 5 * time.Minute) )`
- Watch the `Done` channel in a `go routine` and kill the transaction when there's a signal there
- If the transaction finished successfully in a timely manner, just `cancel` the context and commit the transaction as expected.

2) Using a `Timer`:

- Create a `Timer` with 5 minutes duration
- If the time is over, kill the transaction
- Else, commit the transaction.

Logically speaking, they are the same solution, however, when and how to decide whether to use a `context` with a set Deadline or a good old `Timer`?

Comment: As of 1.8 [`database/sql`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.BeginTx0Z) supports the use of a context. I imagine this could simplify your decision.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer lies in how the [`context.Context`](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#Context) and the [`time.Timer`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Timer) deliver the (cancel) signal.

`context.Context` gives you access to a channel via the `Context.Done()` method **which will be closed** when the goroutines using it should terminate.

`time.Timer` gives you access to a channel in the `Timer.C` struct field **on which a value will be sent** after the given time period (that value will be the current time, but not important here).

There, the key points are highlighted. The channel close may be observed by any number of goroutines, and infinite number of times. [Spec: Receive operator:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Receive_operator)

> A receive operation on a [closed](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Close) channel can always proceed immediately, yielding the element type's [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) after any previously sent values have been received.

So a `Context` may be used to signal cancelation to arbitrary number of goroutines and places. A `Timer` can only be used to signal one target, the one who receives the value from its channel. If multiple clients are listening or trying to receive from its channel, only one will be lucky to receive it.

Also if you're using / working with code that already supports / expects `context.Context`, then it ins't a question which one to use. Go 1.8 also added [more context support](https://golang.org/doc/go1.8#more_context). There have been [significant additions](https://golang.org/doc/go1.8#database_sql) to the [`database/sql`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/) package with context support; including [`DB.BeginTx()`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.BeginTx):

> The provided context is used until the transaction is committed or rolled back. If the context is canceled, the sql package will roll back the transaction. Tx.Commit will return an error if the context provided to BeginTx is canceled.

This is the primary use of `context.Context`: to carry a deadline and signal cancelation across API boundaries, and it's done in a concurrent-safe manner (as `Context` values are immutable, and channels are also safe for concurrent use, data races cannot occur, by design; more on this: [If I am using channels properly should I need to use mutexes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34039229/if-i-am-using-channels-properly-should-i-need-to-use-mutexes/34039377#34039377)).

Related blog posts:

[The Go Blog: Go Concurrency Patterns: Context](https://blog.golang.org/context)

[Pitfalls of context values and how to avoid or mitigate them in Go](https://www.calhoun.io/pitfalls-of-context-values-and-how-to-avoid-or-mitigate-them/)

[Dave Cheney: Context is for cancelation](https://dave.cheney.net/2017/01/26/context-is-for-cancelation)

Comment: I am trying to understand which one should be used for my use-case. I am coming across most of your good posts. Would you please explain `to signal cancelation to arbitrary number of goroutines and places` ? In what scenario, an application will have many Goroutines? any simple example?

Comment: @Gibbs A simple example: you have an HTTP handler which does its work in its goroutine. It may perform logging to database, and it may do so concurrently in a separate goroutine. That separate goroutine may use / monitor the request's context if it needs to abort its work.